# Why is Checkmarx flagging download file response code as an XSS vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, checkmarx

This function is being flagged by *Checkmarx* as vulnerable. I don't understand why.

The error is *Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)* attack:

> The application's async embeds untrusted data in the generated output with `appendChild`, at **line 219** of `src\\containers\\FileUpload\\index.js`. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.
>
> The attacker would be able to alter the returned web page by simply providing modified data in the user input data, which is read by the async method at **line 212** of `src\\containers\\FileUpload\\index.js`. This input then flows through the code straight to the output web page, without sanitization.

Can anyone help?

```js
downloadLink = async (event, url) => {
  event.preventDefault(); 
  let x = url.split("/v1/download-template/");
  let filename = x[1].toUpperCase();
   const response = await axios({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob',
  });
  
  // line 212
  const { data } = response;
  if (data != null && (typeof data === 'object' || data instanceof Blob)) {
    console.log(response)
    const urlBlob = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = urlBlob;
    link.setAttribute('download', `${filename}.csv`);
    // line 219
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.Click();
  }
}
```

[image: image of the code that was just presented]

I tried to sanitize objects using third party library.

Comment: What's line 219? And line 212?

Comment: You're using information from the URL (`filename`) directly in `setAttribute` here: ```link.setAttribute('download', `${fileName}.csv`);``` I can't immediately think of a way that could be used for an XSS attack, but it's the *kind* of thing that these tools are meant to point out.

Comment: #212  const { data } = response;     #219 document.body.appendChild(link);

Comment: There's no react.js in the question?

Comment: It seems that the tool doesn't understand that `createObjectURL` kinda does sanitation.

Comment: Why are you making it this complicated at all? You shouldn't need the axios request - just  directly set `link.href = url`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, this would be possible using direct link (link.href = url) as well. But, is there any way to fixed in this code only?

Comment: @BhausahebSangale File a bug with checkmarx? Ignore the rule? Mark as a false positive? But really, I'd just use the simpler solution if that also works and does not trigger the analyser flag.